# how to get id of button which user know only few characters on other button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a button dynamically whose id is started from "abc" .can we get whole  button id on any other button click ?

I found this `$('[id^=abc]')` some thing but not work for me..?

Comment: what is that _other button_ ? Can you show some more of your html.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want something like this:

```
$('#otherBTN').on("click", function(){
     alert($('[id^="abc"]').attr('id')); // alerts the full id of it
});
```

if you want to make array out of it:

```
$('#otherBTN').on("click", function(){
     var ids = $('[id^="abc"]').map(function(){
                   return this.id;
               }).get();

     console.log(ids); // this logs every id started with abc

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic button id = 'abc'

and in case if you want get id of this on click of another button with id 'xyz'

```
$("#xyz").on('click', function(){

  var BtnIdVal = $("input[type='button'] [id*='abc']").attr("id"); //

});
```

Note - considering only one dynamic button with id='abc'

or

```
$("#xyz").on('click', function(){

      var BtnIdVal = $("input[type='button'] [id^='abc']").attr("id"); //

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#get_id').click(function(){
    alert($('[id^=abc]').attr('id'));
});
```

Here is a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CpYS8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample button set.

```
<button id='abc1'>B1</button>
<button id='abc2'>B2</button>
<button id='abc3'>B3</button>
<button id='abc4'>B4</button>
<button id='abc5'>B5</button>
```

And Jquery click function for each buttons

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^=abc]').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sjnilan/4fHt9/) here. I think this will help you

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#anybuttonid').on("click",function(){

    alert($("[id^='abc']").attr("id"));// by jQuery

});
```

Comment: I want on another button click not same button